# where clause with multiple fields : Arcgis api for javascript

Tags: javascript, api, field

I am tring to perform a query with three fields .I have three combobox,each one is populated with a field values.I want to query with the value selected from combobox for each field.I want to know how to gather the three fields in Where Clause? any idea please?

Comment: While this question does deal with the ArcGIS JSAPI, it is general JavaScript programming question, and is a better fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Orange</option>
<option>Pineapple</option>
<option>Banana</option>
</select>

var si = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
var arrayOfOptionsy=document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
//alert("Index: " + arrayOfOptionsy[si].index + " is " + arrayOfOptionsy[si].text);

query.where = "fruit = '" + arrayOfOptionsy[si].text + "' AND not_gis = '"...
```

Comment: I tried this but the JS code can't recognize the "AND", so how should I proceed? thank you very much :)

Comment: What is your where clause that JS is having a problem with?

Comment: You can alert(query.where); to debug your statement. If your field is text, use single quotes to surround. If your value is a number, no quotes surrounding it. AND should have spaces surrounding it. The alert should look something like this: Title = 'Kool April Nites' AND Website = 'koolaprilnites.com' AND Priority = 1

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is excellent. I'd like to highlight a few tools for handling this kind of thing.

### [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

The jQuery interface makes working with the DOM in JavaScript much simpler. For example, lets say you had a form:

```
<label>Latitude<input id="latitude" type="number" step=".01" min="-90" max="90 /></label>
<label>Longitutde<input id="longitutde" type="number" step=".01" min="-180" max="180" /></label>
<select id="radius">
    <option>1 km</option>
    <option>5 km</option>
    <option>20 km</option>
</select>
```

You could then grab the current information in the form for use in constructing a where clause as follows:

```
var lat = $('#latitude').val();  // $('#latitude') is the element with id 'latitude'
var lon = $('#longitude').val(); // and .val() grabs the current value of that input
var rad = $('#radius').val();    // and this syntax works with various input elements
```

### [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)

The Knockout framework allows you to declaratively link DOM elements to JavaScript variables so changing them in the DOM immediately changes them in the JavaScript. Also, you are able to grab the change events which allows you to reprocess the data when needed. In this example, you may want to query the database every time your field changes. Here's how to do it:

```
<label>Latitude<input data-bind="value: lat" type="number" step=".01" min="-90" max="90 /></label>
<label>Longitutde<input data-bind="value: lon" type="number" step=".01" min="-180" max="180" /></label>
<select data-bind="options: ['1 km', '5 km', '20 km'], value: rad"></select>
```

In Knockout, you use 'data-bind="value: var"' to select the variable to bind to the DOM element. In the JavaScript, you have:

```
var queryModel = {          // we create the "data model" to be used in the DOM
    lat: ko.observable(0),  // and wrap each value in a ko.observable(); we can 
    lon: ko.observable(),   // assign default values or leave them empty
    rad: ko.observable(),
    query: ko.computed(function() {
        // query processing here; to access the variable values use this.lat(),
        // this.lon(), this.rad(); you can then access this variable in JavaScript
        // using queryModel.query()
    }, this)
};

queryModel.query.subscribe(function(query) {
    // this function will be called every time the query variable is recomputed; you
    // may add code here that would run this query every time the query updates
});

ko.bind('queryModel'); // and finally, we "bind" the data model to the DOM
```

Though this is obviously a little more complicated than the jQuery model, it is a powerful tool since it allows you to reactively process the data as it is updated in the DOM.